# UI utility library for OpenGL 3+, or is Xlib ok?

Tags: linux, opengl, sdl, xlib

I want to write some OpenGL 3.2, likely also OpenGL 4 stuff on Linux, and I just saw that libsdl 1.2 (the latest stable release) supports only 2.x. LibSDL 1.3 (which is in development) should support it, but it'll be a while before it gets into mainstream distributions. Is there any library out there *right now* which allows me to create an OpenGL window with a context of my choice, and preferably also help me with the input?

If not, is there some small library which reduces the pain with Xlib? My Windows path for OpenGL is written with plain-old WinAPI, with own message pump etc., and I wonder if X11 is worse than that. A quick web search indicates that one should use a library above Xlib. I'd be happy with something that just wraps XLib, so I can do the OpenGL context on my own with glX if XLib is really that horrible.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

GLFW (GL Framework) supports creating 3.0+ contexts, and has input support, you can read about it on:

- http://gpwiki.org/index.php/GLFW
- http://www.glfw.org/

Sadly, the main page is down now.

Comment: Thanks, seems to be exactly what I want, and even under zlib.

Comment: Where is doc about creating OpenGL context version of my choice? Cant find function responsible for it.